# I am stuck in MySQL stored procedure

Tags: mysql

I have to replace incorrect multiple data at a time so I used preg_replace but I am stuck because it only replace in style spelling mistake. There are multiple different incorrect style and I want to replace all of them in one standard style, so I am using a cursor. But it is giving me a syntax error.

I have attached my query.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE addcorrect()
BEGIN
DECLARE ADDRESS char(90);
DECLARE badaddress CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT 
           supplementtal_address_1
FROM aditi_po
    WHERE ((
    UPPER( street_name ) LIKE '%P%BOX%'
    OR UPPER( supplementtal_address_1 ) LIKE 'P%BOX%'
    )
    AND id NOT IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM aditi_po
    WHERE (street_name LIKE '%PO %Box%'
        or supplementtal_address_1 LIKE '%PO %Box%')
    ));

  OPEN badaddress

  read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH badaddress INTO ADDRESS;

    IF done THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
    if ADDRESS LIKE '%P.O. Box%' THEN 
        print ADDRESS = PREG_REPLACE('/(.*?)(P.O. Box)/' , '$1PO Box' ,ADDRESS)
    ELSE ADDRESS LIKE '%P.O. Box%' THEN print ADDRESS = PREG_REPLACE('/(.*?)(P.O. Box)/' , '$1PO Box' ,ADDRESS)
       END IF;
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE badaddress;
END;
```

MySQL said:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

Comment: So comment out parts until the error goes away. Then you've either found the problem yourself or have a "real" SO question. (There is too much cruft here for this to be applicable; it's a "fix my code" review.) Hopefully you're trying it on the CLI or similar.

Comment: Actually i have tried that way also but it's not working I wanted to know where i am wrong.

Comment: Try adding a `;` at the end of line 1.

Comment: Yes to @pst; OP, remove parts of your code until the error goes away. Once you've done some basic debugging work (an absolutely essential skill to learn) then you will have either solved it, or will have a more concrete question to ask here.

Comment: Also, I didn't really understand your first paragraph - it didn't make a lot of sense in English. Could you maybe reword?

Answer (score 0):

This fragment looks bad:

```
ELSE ADDRESS LIKE '%P.O. Box%' THEN 
    print ADDRESS = PREG_REPLACE('/(.*?)(P.O. Box)/' , '$1PO Box' ,ADDRESS)
```

I believe you want:

```
ELSEIF ADDRESS LIKE '%P.O. Box%' THEN 
    print ADDRESS = PREG_REPLACE('/(.*?)(P.O. Box)/', '$1PO Box', ADDRESS)
```